# Una pagina web en una app movil

Tags: wordpress, ionic, phonegap, framework7

alguien me podria decir si es posible convertir cierta seccion de una pagina en wordpress dentro de una app, el diseño se haria con phonegap y framework7.

Yo solo quiero que se visualicen 3 paginas en concreto desde la app, el resto de la pagina no me interesa que se vea, ni los menu ni nada mas.

Espero que alguien pueda guiarme un poco, un saludo y gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola. Bienvenido a [es.so].  Te recomiendo [edit] la pregunta agregando algo de información como que has probado o que has encontrado por Internet, y sería bueno que realices el [tour] y leer [ask]. La idea es ofrecer un [mcve] en todas las preguntas.

Comment: Sí se puede hacer, llamando (mediante la app) un webview de sólo la página que quieras, pero la página no debe tener un link externo, si no se abriría en la app.

Comment: ¿y hay alguna forma de quitar la cabecera de la pagina para que no se vea en la app?

Comment: Desde Wordpress 4.7 viene includo con el una api rest, que la puedes consumir desde cualquier tipo de app y preguntar a ella por ciertas paginas y su contenido.

Comment: ¿y hay alguna forma de quitar la cabecera de la pagina para que no se vea en la app si se mete en un iframe?